# Docker container: lsmod not found

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

How can I get `lsmod` and `modprobe` installed in Ubuntu 14 that is running on Docker? I need to install a device driver in the container, but first I need these commands.

(The docker image is originally from docker hub, from a tomcat:7 image).

Comment: `apt-get install kmod` should do it, but I don't think you can load kernel modules in a Docker container. You need to load them on the host.

Comment: @IanAbbott so what happens if you use lsmod in containers?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Based on comment from @lan-Abbott. Problem is solved.

```
user@host:# apt-get install kmod
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libkmod2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  kmod
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libkmod2
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 249 not upgraded.
Need to get 135 kB of archives.
After this operation, 212 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libkmod2 kmod
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Get:1 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main libkmod2 amd64 22-1.1 [47.9 kB]
Get:2 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main kmod amd64 22-1.1 [86.6 kB]
Fetched 135 kB in 10s (12.8 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
(Reading database ... 20886 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libkmod2_22-1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkmod2:amd64 (22-1.1) over (18-3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u4) ...
Setting up libkmod2:amd64 (22-1.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package kmod.
(Reading database ... 20886 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/kmod_22-1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kmod (22-1.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u4) ...
Setting up kmod (22-1.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u4) ...


user@host#:ls /sbin/
        modinfo           insmod             lsmod      .... ....
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for